# Magento delete database

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I have two sites runnning in the same database.
One in magento and one not.

My question is:
Which files are from magento because I didnt use a prefix and I don't want to delete tables from the other site.

Comment: well, 1 idea would be to install a blank copy of magento, and match and delete the tables.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here (http://pastebin.com/mzEwpCZW) you can find a list of tables of one of our installations (1.7.0.2). Keep in mind though that there can be differences between our installation caused b

Otherwise just install clean magento and make a list.

Comment: It depends on the version and the 3rd party modules installed. For a more definitive list that will better match your installed version, you can consult MageReverse. http://www.magereverse.com/